# How can I make a host directory mount with the container directory's contents?

Tags: docker

What I am trying to do is set up a docker container for ghost where I can easily modify the theme and other content.  So I am making /opt/ghost/content a volume and mounting that on the host.

It looks like I will have to manually copy the theme into the host directory because when I mount it, it is an empty directory.  So my content directory is totally empty. I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong.

I have tried a few different variations including using ADD with default themes folder, putting VOLUME at the end of the Dockerfile.  I keep ending up with an empty content directory.

Does anyone have a Dockerfile doing something similar that is already working that I can look at?

Or maybe I can use the `docker cp` command somehow to populate the volume?

I may be missing something obvious or have made a silly mistake in my attempts to achieve this.  But the basic thing is I want to be able to upload a new set of files into the ghost themes directory using a host-mounted volume and also have the casper theme in there by default.

This is what I have in my Dockerfile right now:

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04
MAINTAINER Jason Livesay "ithkuil@gmail.com"

RUN apt-get install -y python-software-properties
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
RUN echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main universe" > /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get -qq update
RUN apt-get install -y sudo curl unzip nodejs=0.10.20-1chl1~precise1
RUN curl -L https://en.ghost.org/zip/ghost-0.3.2.zip > /tmp/ghost.zip
RUN useradd ghost
RUN mkdir -p /opt/ghost
WORKDIR /opt/ghost
RUN unzip /tmp/ghost.zip
RUN npm install --production

# Volumes
RUN mkdir /data

ADD run /usr/local/bin/run
ADD config.js /opt/ghost/config.js
ADD content /opt/ghost/content/
RUN chown -R ghost:ghost /opt/ghost

ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV GHOST_URL http://my-ghost-blog.com
EXPOSE 2368

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/run"]
VOLUME ["/data", "/opt/ghost/content"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, empty host-mounted (bound) volumes still will not receive contents of directories set up during the build, BUT data containers referenced with --volumes-from WILL.

So now I think the answer is, rather than writing code to work around non-initialized host-mounted volumes, forget host-mounted volumes and instead use data containers.

Data containers use the same image as the one you are trying to persist data for (so they have the same directories etc.).

`docker run -d --name myapp_data mystuff/myapp echo Data container for myapp`

Note that it will run and then exit, so your data containers for volumes won't stay running.  If you want to keep them running you can use something like `sleep infinity` instead of `echo`, although this will obviously take more resources and isn't necessary or useful unless you have some specific reason -- like assuming that all of your relevant containers are still running.

You then use `--volumes-from` to use the directories from the data container:

`docker run -d --name myapp --volumes-from myapp_data`

https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

Answer (score 3):

<strike>You need to place the VOLUME directive before actually adding content to it.</strike>

My answer is completely wrong! [Look here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/docker-user/volume%2420copy/docker-user/miGVsRyY_-E/xpXDNXZAEMUJ) it seems there is actually a bug. If the VOLUME command happens after the directory already exists in the container, then changes are not persisted.

The Dockerfile should always end with a CMD or an ENTRYPOINT.

**UPDATE**

My solution would be to ADD files in the container home directory, then use a shell script as an entry point in which I'll copy the file in the shared volume and do all the other tasks.

Comment: Thank you.. I tried that, doesn't seem to make a difference as far as getting my content to appear in my host mounted volume.

Comment: How are you running your container?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update.  I will try again. I have also been following this https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/1992 because it seems related.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking into the same thing. The problem I encountered was that I was using a relative local mount path, something like:

```
docker run -i -t -v ../data:/opt/data image
```

Switching to an absolute local path fixed this up for me:

```
docker run -i -t -v /path/to/my/data:/opt/data image
```

Can you confirm whether you were doing a relative path, and whether this helps?

Comment: Nope, not using a relative path, and I think you misunderstood the question.  I am not having trouble using volumes in general.

I am trying to get it to use the contents that I ADDed when my host volume directory is empty or missing.  Are you able to achieve that?

Comment: I believe that if they were starting over now, they might have made it do that, but since it didn't before, it would be a major breaking change.  So it doesn't do that, it just uses whatever is in the host volume directory, if that is blank, it wont initialize it for you with the contents from the container.

Far as I can tell I just have to write a script to copy it manually if its not there as part of my container startup.

Comment: Oh I see, apologies. No, never attempted that. On a side note, I came across this while trying to do something pretty similar to what you mentioned, which is now (basically) working: https://github.com/unwitting/docker_ghost :)

Answer (score 0):

Docker V1.8.1 preserves data in a volume if you mount it with the run command. From [the docker docs:](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/)

```
Volumes are initialized when a container is created. If the container’s 
base image contains data at the specified mount point, that existing 
data is copied into the new volume upon volume initialization.
```

Example: An image defines the

```
/var/www/html
```

as a volume and populates it with the data of a web application. Your docker hosts provides a mount directory

```
/my/host/dir
```

You start the image by

```
docker run -v /my/host/dir:/var/www/html image
```

then you will get all the data from /var/www/html in the hosts /my/host/dir
This data will persist even if you delete the container or the image.

Comment: Is this new in 1.8.1?  Didn't used to do that if I understand you correctly.  If someone can confirm then we need to change the answer.

Comment: The rule you mentioned does not apply to mounting host directory. It's only for Data volumes.

Comment: @Paul: What's the difference? Data volume is seen from the perspective of the docker image, host directory is the target where the data volume is mapped to, isn't it?

Comment: @Jason: I tried it out with a data directory of MySql.

Comment: @Heri open a link your provided and search for "If the container’s base image contains data at the specified mount point, that existing data is copied into the new volume upon volume initialization. (Note that this does not apply when mounting a host directory.)".